# What's the right thing to do when I post a question, then realize the entire premise was wrong?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted a question related to a HIGHLY specific/localized issue (or at least I thought it was) and after posting, I realized that the entire premise of my question was false. Someone has already posted a possible solution and has received upvotes etc. I thought that Java and GTK were interfering with my openGL calls in C++ and it all turned out to be an entirely different issue, where the culprit was timer resolution on FPS throttling being very poor and thus variable. So my question is, should I delete me question, edit to to explain the whole mess and post the answer/solution? I don't want to screw over people who received upvotes for making an effort to help me.... will they those that rep? (So I guess this is 2 or more questions in 1 :D). Thanks!

P.S. In case anyone cares, here is a [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510589/java-opengl-and-gtk-based-apps-screwing-up-c-opengl)... which is.. in question. :D

Comment: This gets asked somewhat frequently... here's [one similar post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73354/whats-etiquette-for-answering-my-own-question-when-i-realize-it-shouldnt-have). As for the rep, yeah, [rep changes due to deleted posts vanish on recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep) (I'll edit that into the reputation FAQ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would flag for moderator attention and ask for it to be closed as Too Localized, explaining why it's not a valid question.  I would leave a comment on the question with the same explanation as well so that future visitors know what happened.

Comment: +1; I think this is best. I have already voted to close it

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Flagged and voted to close my own question... haha

Answer (score 3):

If I were in your case?

1. Select the most helpful answer as correct
2. Edit your question to clarify your misunderstanding or leave a comment on the selected answer with this information
3. Run
4. Never do this again

Comment: lol +1 for making me laugh and I was considering this but honestly the actual issue is so unrelated that the "Edit" would actually require a full re-write. That's why I don't want to go this route. Also it was an honest mistake. Technically these programs were interfering with my application, but it all came down to timer resolution and nothing to do with render calls. :(

Comment: @AscensionSystems: Then don't edit; just leave a comment on the selected answer and briefly describe what was going on.  I do think you should select the best answer no matter what you do.

Comment: Comments on answers are easily lost; I'd suggest an edit at the top of the question to clearly indicate that the premise of the question is wrong to discourage further efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Once a question gets an upvoted answer, *you* cannot delete it.

I would just put an edit in your question explaining the flawed premise, accept the answer (if it's accurate) and move on.

If it's a question you *really* don't want your name associated with, you can flag a mod and ask her to delete it.

Comment: Once a question gets an upvoted answer, it cannot be deleted __by the asker__. A mod could still do it, if there were a good reason.